# Kill second instance of a process

Tags: debian, ubuntu, process, raspbian

I'm running two instances of omxiv (Omx Image Viewer). The first instance acts like a background image, and the second instance acts as a slideshow. My question is how can I specifically kill the second instance?

Small note: The second instance will always be opened after the first instance.

I was thinking about killing it by pid, but I am not sure if it will have the same pid after the reboot, therefore this might not work.

Right now I am calling:

```
pkill -9 omxiv
```

which is terminating both instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pkill` has a `-n` flag that will make it only affect the most recently started ("newest") matching process.

```
pkill -n omxiv
```

If the `omxiv` process is well behaved, there is no need to use `-9`.

There is also a `-o` flag that will make `pkill` send a signal to the oldest matching process.

Note that using `pkill -n` will always kill the newest instance.  If you have three processes, it will kill the third, not the second (as per title of question).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, it works great. Thanks for explanation

Comment: According to the man page, this also works on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @kasperd I was a bit careful, because OpenBSD `pkill` has some options not implemented on Linux systems, for example `-q` to be quiet.